# No network after upgrade to 18.04 (from 17.10)

Tags: networking, upgrade, 18.04, network-manager, internet

After a lot of upgrading (I think 1000 packages since I didn't upgrade for a long time), I can connect to wireless networks, but I can't ping anything. It says name or service not known. Firefox will immediately fail to load any page.

I even tried my tethered usb connection from my phone which I used a lot and it won't even appear as connected. Even Bluetooth tether won't work.

Some output which might be helpful:

[image]

I use ufw firewall but it is disabled.

**UPDATE:**

I 'fixed' it by adding google DNS servers on `resolv.conf`. I'm connecting normally but I keep receiving notifications: "network activation failed", but it still works without any problems. Maybe I did not attack the source of the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You've provided a photograph of text, copy & pasting the actual text, plus a vague error message (please copy & paste the actual error message exactly).  I think your picture shows a connection (a 192.68.* ip address), so can you ping your router?  If that works, can you ping google's dns (8.8.8.8)?  If you can then I finally try human names, eg. google.com (which tests DNS or what converts names like google.com to the numbers that the IP address really is)

Comment: Sorry about the picture, I only have my phone now do I can't paste the text itself

Comment: You're right, it's a DNS problem. 8.8.8.8 pings ok

Comment: I tried putting 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS servers in resolv.conf and restarting networking and it didn't work

Comment: If you added the nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf` correctly; it would have worked **until** you restarted networking (which re-creates that file & would have wiped out your changes).  As a temporary fix; add the nameservers again to the file, but DO NOT restart networking (restarting the service, or a reboot causes the resolv.conf file to be re-created)

Comment: I rebooted and now things work. I don't have a problem having dns setted up this way but should this be the solution?

Comment: Everything works now but I keep receiving notifications "network activation failed". It's very annoying.